# Putting text in a number input doesn't trigger change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mnpenner/w7bLu/)

It appears that entering text into `<input type="number"/>` does not trigger a change event. I would like a change event so that I can warn the user to fix their input. How can I get a change event for this, *and get the current value* so that I can verify the bad input?

I've been testing in Chrome.

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
    alert('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
put letters in me and press tab: <input type="number"/>
```

Comment: An event is triggered on Chrome, but only after you press one of the arrows and then type other stuff.

Comment: I get the event in Firefox... but I don't know if they support the `type=number` input. I don't get any arrows.

Comment: The change is triggered on blur with text

Comment: @Musa: `blur` fires at the right time, but how do I get the value? `this.value` returns an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [pickypg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/706724/pickypg) has noted, if a user types '**abcd**' into an `<input type='number'>` element, you cannot get the value `'abcd'` via `$(this).val()`.  (Caveat:  I've only tested in Chrome.)

However, you can determine whether the HTML5 input validity constraints are satisfied (valid) or not by calling `myDOMelement.checkValidity()`, or looking at the individual properties of the `myDOMelement.validity` object.  This at least lets you distinguish between a blank field (valid) and one containing '**abcd**' (not valid).  Check [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/) for more on HTML5 validity.

What is rather confusing, at least in Chrome, is that if an `<input type='number'>` element is initially blank and then you type in '**abcd**', the `'change'` event is ***not*** fired on blur.  Likewise when you delete '**abcd**' from the field so the field becomes blank.

A workaround is testing for changes in the HTML5 validity on blur.  Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Martin_ATS/qyKkY/) to illustrate the technique.  Note that you still cannot tell if the user has changed '**abcd**' to '**efgh**', since those are both not valid.

Comment: A note from the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type=number)):  

"If the value of the element is not a valid floating-point number, then set it to the empty string instead."

Answer (score 10):

Try using the other keyboard events then. For example, I just added

```
$("input").on('keyup', function() {
    alert('keyup' + $(this).val());
})
```

To your JSFiddle example, and the `alert` appears after pressing `a` within the `number` textbox.

Note: Checking `$(this).val()` will not return you invalid characters (at least in Chrome). It strips invalid values before returning the result (e.g., `1a` becomes blank).  This is also why the `change` event appears to not be fired when its value hasn't actually changed because the input is all invalid. To catch invalid characters, you must instead check the event's `keyCode`:

```
$("input").on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) {
        // not 0-9 (note: ignores -)
        alert('error!');
    }
});
```

After [messing around a bit more](http://jsfiddle.net/AwhWf/6/), I noticed that Chrome and IE10 behave similarly, but IE10 seems to have a bug in its stripping:

If you start the `number` input with a non-number, then IE10 (possibly 9 as well) will consider the rest of the input to be a valid number regardless of what characters follow (e.g., `1a2` is just as valid as `12` in the eyes of IE).  However, in Chrome, if you enter a non-number, then it will immediately ignore the input and declare it to be invalid; in IE10, if you start with a non-number, then the behavior is the same.

One big difference in behavior is that IE10 will clear an invalid number field after `blur`, but, again, they only consider it invalid if the field starts with a non-number (e.g., `a1`).  `-` can precede numbers, but not more than one of them.

In both browsers, if the `number` is considered invalid, then `this.value` (and consequently `$(this).val()`) will return blank. In IE10, you can be get the raw, invalid value if the `number` starts with a number (`0-9`).  Both browsers will only fire `change` events when they consider the input to have actually changed and--in IE10's case--that means if the user enters `abcd` and then `blur`s the input, then IE10 will clear the field and fire a `change` event *if* it had a valid value before being changed.  In Chrome, the change occurs whether the input is valid or not; if it's invalid then it is changed to a blank value.

What this means is that you can handle valid and invalid number input, but you cannot dependably get the actual value that the user has typed into the textbox.

HTML

```
put letters in me and press tab:
<br />
<input type="number"/>
<br />
<p id="event" />
<p id="text" />
```

JavaScript

```
function checkValid(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("#event").text(e.type);
    $("#text").html("this.value: " +
                    this.value +
                    "<br />$(this).val(): " +
                    $this.val() + "<br />$(this).is(:valid): " +
                    $this.is(":valid") +
                    "<br />$.isNumeric(this.value): " +
                    $.isNumeric(this.value)); // <- helps check
}

$('input[type="number"]').on('change', checkValid).on("keyup", checkValid);
```

You can check to see if it is a valid number by checking `$.isNumeric`. The `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo classes do not work in IE10 with `number` except when the field is marked as `required` (not at all in IE9), but they both work in Chrome without marking it as `required`.

Comment: I was hoping I could get it to fire at the same time onchange would. Maybe `blur` is more suitable.

Comment: If Chrome simply didn't allow you to type non-numbers in the box, this behaviour would be fine..but even by checking the key-codes it's difficult to tell if there's any "text" in the box. How would we figure out when they've cleared out the bad characters? Do we have to count how many keys they've typed, and match it with how many backspaces (which would be totally unreliable)?

Answer (score 0):

The event change is triggered on losing focus and it is working as it is supposed to be, you may need to use `keyup`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/w7bLu/1/)**

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
    alert('change');
});
```