# jquery mobile function on.change works only sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vvkvxef/), this code is supposed to check for invalid numerical values like -12-12. So the bug arises if I type an invalid numerical value (eg. -12-11) it removes the input (which is the expected behavior) and the weird part is that the second time it doesn't call the document.on change function.

The steps to reproduce the problem are as follows:

- Type 12 for example.
- Click somewhere else like the other textbox and that number will be
  converted to decimal (12.00)
- Type and incorrect number like -12-12 and click somewhere else and
  the textbox will get cleared out (which is the expected behaviour).
- The second time you type that number in the textbox it doesn't change
  the value or clear the textbox.

  This is something that I don't understand, by trying to debug the code the second time you insert a wrong number that function doesn't get called so I was wondering why.

Any help is appreciated.

*My javascript code:*

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="number"]', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    var max = target.attr('max') - 0;
    var min = target.attr('min') - 0;
    var step = target.attr('step');
    var val = parseFloat(target.val());
    if(typeof max !== 'undefined' && val > max) {
        target.val(max);
    }
    else if(typeof min !== 'undefined' && val < min) {
        target.val(min);
    }
    else if(typeof step !== 'undefined') {
        if(step < 1) {
            target.val(parseFloat(target.val()).toFixed(step.split('.')[1].length));
        }
        else {
            debugger;
        }
    }
    else if(val + '' != target.val()) {
        target.val(val);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's working fine with regards to your expected behavior. 12 changes to 12.00, -12 changes to 0.01 and -12-12 clears the box.

Comment: Is not working the second time you enter this number: -12-12

Comment: I got it, seems like it's a browser support issue. It occurs every time when textbox is filled after it's been cleared out. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111491/putting-text-in-a-number-input-doesnt-trigger-change-event, there are some workarounds. However I would suggest to not use number type input as it's not stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your issue, and able to solve it. I suggest you to use `blur` event instead of `change` event of `textbox`. This will work like a charm.

**Here is the code :**

```js
$(document).on('blur', 'input[type="number"]', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    var max = target.attr('max') - 0;
    var min = target.attr('min') - 0;
    var step = target.attr('step');
    var val = parseFloat(target.val());
    if(typeof max !== 'undefined' && val > max) {
        target.val(max);
    }
    else if(typeof min !== 'undefined' && val < min) {
        target.val(min);
    }
    else if(typeof step !== 'undefined') {
        if(step < 1) {
            target.val(parseFloat(target.val()).toFixed(step.split('.')[1].length));
        }
        else {
            debugger;
        }
    }
    else if(val + '' != target.val()) {
        target.val(val);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="transaction_amount">Amount</label>
                <input type="number" data-mini="true" step="0.01" name="amount" min="0.01" max="1000000" id="transaction_amount" value="">
                <label for="transaction_external_identifier" id="payment-description-label">Check #</label>
                <input type="text" name="external_identifier" id="transaction_external_identifier" value="" data-mini="true">
```

Answer (score 2):

When an invalid number is entered into the number type input, the browser regards that as blank (because it's invalid and it won't bother holding that value, so returns false when asked about validity. [According to the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity)). So if you type -12-12 again, the `change` event doesn't fire and hence it doesn't clear out because the underlying value is still blank. You'll see this if you first start with entering -12-12 into the blank input - it also won't work.

Your best bet is to change the `onchange` to `onblur` as it will be far more consistent since it doesn't look at the value.